# How to make a folder not compile to js using tsconfig

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I'm trying to create a npx package and to do so, i need to convert my .ts files into .js. The application i am making basically spits out typeScript templates to users according to the options they select.
So, in this app, basically there is a CLI (`index.ts`) and the `'templates'` folder. If i nest all of this into a `'src'` folder and add `rootDir: "./src"` to `tsconfig`, what i want in the end is `tsconfig` to not compile with the `"./src/templates"` folder but copy it in the `"dist"` folder it generates and compile the `"index.ts"` file only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide your config? Did you try `"exclude": ["./src/templates"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question in simple sense, you **cannot** selectively choose not to compile a certain folder included in `rootDir`. As a workaround for the problem though, what i did was compile `index.ts` file only into the `dist` folder and then copy the `templates` folder into the `dist` folder.